# Past and Present Perfect confusion

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, present-tense

I have a sentence

```
She has drunk milk
```

This sentence refer to Past Perfect but how its different from Present Perfect ? As both (past and present perfect tense) verb's present the `past` ? How can I prove that this sentence is Past Perfect not Present Perfect.

Thanks

Comment: Your sentence is *not* Past Perfect - it's **Present** Perfect. The Past Perfect version would be *"She **had** drunk milk"*. Do you still have a question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers We need to use `had` with He/She/It/I/They in Past Perfect ? Can't we use `has,have` in Past Perfect ?

Comment: The difference between Past Perfect and Present Perfect is *exactly and only* that in Past Perfect constructions the auxiliary verb *to have* takes the ***past*** (not ***present***) form. Read more about it [**here**.](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html)

Comment: I'll wait to see what others think about this question, but my impression is it's probably General Reference if all you needed was the information in my comments above. If you're still confused, please feel free to *edit the question text* to clarify what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am still reading but as far what I read I am reading that `drunk` is irregular verb , so we need to use `has` with it in `Past Perfect` , as a reference you can check here http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/irregular_verbs.htm

Comment: I'm sure you've misunderstood that page (I can't see anything saying *has drunk* is "past perfect"). You're just being confused by the fact that ***to drink*** is an irregular verb, so the *Past Participle* ***drunk*** isn't the same as the Simple Past ***drank***. Both Past Perfect and Present Perfect require the Past Participle, so *"She had/has **drank** the milk"* is simply "ungrammatical" (but even native speakers sometimes get that wrong! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things to learn in *past and present perfect*. That said, *actually*, the question is broad. But I'll try to restrict my answer that precisely addresses your concern and you might find it helpful.

You said - *She has drunk milk* refers to *past perfect* - *wrong!*

And you want to learn the difference between past/present perfect.

The gist of those tenses lie in the structure of the sentence and its context.

In most of the cases, we use *the present perfect* while referring something that started in the past but its effects are still in the present.

Say...

> She *has lived* in this apartment all her life

The sentence structure is `has/have + past participle`

Now, when we use *the past perfect*, we refer thing that are already happened in the past. **And** we may also want to point something before that time.

The structure is `had + past participle`

> She *had lived* in this apartment all her life - she's dead now!

I found the best reference of [British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/past-perfect) to learn the past perfect. Check out the nuance of *past simple* and *past perfect* on the page.

So, do you now see how do you differentiate these usages?

Getting back to your concern - *She has drunk milk* - you said it past perfect. Do you realize now? Check the sentence structure... :)